# Google analytics API missing data?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am trying to access data via the analytics reportingv4 API. I am using the.net version in visual studio. I can get it to return data but just not the data I want.

I am using a specific account that only has one view attached to it. If I try to view the data I'm looking for, using the web interface, it works, by filtering it using the search box. For example, there is currently 20 page hits for today. If I try the same, using the API, no data is returned. If I remove the filter, from my code, data is returned but none of the pages that I am looking for.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the code for your API call

Answer (score 0):

I was being silly. I eventually noticed that I was supplying a date range for the year 2017! The processing which